# Closed-form for $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (n)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, dirichlet-series, prime-gaps

Is there a closed form for $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (n)^2}$$ (where $\pi (x)$ is the number of primes less than or equal to x)?

It's obvious that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (n)^s}$$ converges for $s>1$ by observing the inequality $\pi(x)>\frac{x}{\ln(x)}>x^k$ for $k<1$ and  $x$ greater than some finite positive integer. If any extra information can be given about the generalization $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (n)^s}$, that would be great too.

**EDIT:**

So far, I've discovered the following

Define $$f(s)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (n)^s}$$

Then $f(s)$ is equal to the Dirichlet series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{g_n}{n^s},$$ where $g_n$ is the *n*th prime gap.

Then by using Abel's summation formula, $f(s)$ is equal to the improper integral $$s \int_1^{\infty} \frac{p_{\lfloor u+1 \rfloor}-2}{u^{1+s}} du,$$ where $p_n$ is the *n*th prime number.

Hope that helps

Comment: No I do not think there is. What is your motivation?

Comment: @OpenSeason I've recently been looking at infinite series and I came up with this question myself. I don't know if it has any significance, but it does look interesting.